Generate a Histogram with multiple charts of a Word Table
I am working on a VBA macro in Microsoft Word that is supposed to generate a histogram ( Clustered Column ) from data in a table within the document Word.
How can I modify the macro to have multiple grouped charts within the same category, as shown in the image below, using the following table?


I have used the following code to accomplish this task:
Sub CreateWordChart()
    Dim oChart As Chart, oTable As Table
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' get the first table in Doc
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)  ' modify as needed
    Set oChart = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    Set oSheet = oChart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
    ' get the size of Word table
    RowCnt = oTable.Rows.Count
    ColCnt = oTable.Columns.Count
    With oSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
        ' remove content
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
        ' resize Table1
        .Resize oSheet.Range("A1").Resize(RowCnt, ColCnt)
        ' copy Word table to Excel table
        oTable.Range.Copy
        .Range.Select
        .Parent.Paste
    End With
    oChart.PlotBy = xlRows
    oChart.ChartData.Workbook.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

And I obtained this result, which is not the same as the previous picture:

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

You should reference your previous question about this, even though they are not identical, they are certainly related. Is your code based on that supplied by Taller? That should also be noted if so. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78399435/generate-a-histogram-of-a-word-table

The data source needs to be transformed into a standard 2D table.

How can I do this please ?


If you could organize the table in Word as shown below, then the code is simple.



Otherwise, you need more code lines to covert data source for chart.

Option Explicit

Sub CreateWordChart3()
    Dim oChart As Chart, oTable As Table
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Const START_CELL = "AA1"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' get the first table in Doc
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)  ' modify as needed
    Set oChart = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    Set oSheet = oChart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
    oTable.Range.Copy
    oSheet.Range(START_CELL).Select
    oSheet.Paste
    Call Create2DTable(oSheet, oSheet.Range(START_CELL))
    oChart.ChartData.Workbook.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Create2DTable(ByRef tmpSheet As Worksheet, startCell As Excel.Range)
    Dim oDicCat As Object, oDicSt As Object, sKey, vKey
    Dim rCell As Excel.Range, rC As Excel.Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set oDicCat = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oDicSt = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    With startCell.CurrentRegion
        ' get the unique CatX list
        For Each rCell In .Rows(2).Cells
            If Len(rCell) > 0 Then
                oDicCat(rCell.Value) = ""
            End If
        Next
        ' loop through table
        For Each rCell In .Rows(1).Cells
            sKey = rCell
            If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
                If Not oDicSt.Exists(sKey) Then
                    Set oDicSt(sKey) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
                    For Each vKey In oDicCat
                        oDicSt(sKey)(vKey) = ""
                    Next
                End If
                ' store values with nested Dict
                For Each rC In rCell.Offset(1).Resize(1, rCell.MergeArea.Count)
                    oDicSt(sKey)(rC.Value) = rC.Offset(1).Value
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Dim xlTab As Excel.ListObject
    Set xlTab = tmpSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    xlTab.DataBodyRange.Delete
    ' get the size of output table
    Dim RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
    RowCnt = oDicSt.Count: ColCnt = oDicCat.Count
    xlTab.Resize tmpSheet.Range("A1").Resize(RowCnt + 1, ColCnt + 1)
    With xlTab.Range
        .Cells(1, 1) = "REQ"
        For i = 1 To ColCnt
            .Cells(1, i + 1) = oDicCat.keys()(i - 1)
        Next
        ' populate output
        For j = 1 To RowCnt
            sKey = oDicSt.keys()(j - 1)
            .Cells(j + 1, 1) = sKey
            For i = 1 To ColCnt
                .Cells(j + 1, i + 1) = oDicSt(sKey)(.Cells(1, i + 1).Text)
            Next
        Next
    End With
    startCell.CurrentRegion.Clear
End Sub





Thank you so much. It works very well now

One more question please, How can I adjust the code to position my histogram below table 12, for instance, in my document?

What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?
